# Password protect a folder in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: encryption, security, privacy

I would like to have the option to right click on a folder, and be able to protect its access with a password. How do I do that?

I know it is possible to do it in other distributions, but I want to have that option on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Thanks